# Average case and worst case time complexity of recurrence algorithm containing if and while loop

Tags: loops, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

I am confused about how to write the recurrence equation and solving it without using master theorem to show the average case and worst case time complexity of the question.

[image]

I tried to write the equation but I don’t think its true. Also, im not sure that is it the same method for proving big O and big theta notation.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is primarily for practical programming questions. Theoretical CS questions are a better fit for [cs.se].

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to cs, thanks for the information.